# Cocos2dx animation ( not using deprecated methods)

Tags: c++, objective-c, animation, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to understand how animations works on `cocos2dx` (I'm developing on OSX for IPad target).

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d) trying to traduce from `objective-c` to `C++`.

Here's my code:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("oras.plist");

CCSpriteBatchNode* spriteBatchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("oras.png", 8);
this->addChild(spriteBatchNode);

CCAnimation *bearWalkingAnimation = CCAnimation::create();

for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i )
{

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "bear" << i + 1  << ".png";

    std::string name = ss.str();
    CCSpriteFrame* sprite =  CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(name.c_str());
    bearWalkingAnimation->addSpriteFrame(sprite);


}

CCSpriteFrame *startSpriteFrame = static_cast<CCSpriteFrame *> (bearWalkingAnimation->getFrames()->objectAtIndex(0));

//deprecated
CCSprite *startSprite = CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrameName("bear1.png"); 
startSprite->setPosition(ccp (size.width / 2 , size.height / 2));

CCAnimate *bearAnimate = CCAnimate::create(bearWalkingAnimation);

CCRepeatForever * animAction = CCRepeatForever::create(bearAnimate);
startSprite->runAction(animAction);

this->addChild(startSprite);
```

Bear is rendered correctly but not animated.
I have 2 questions:

- **First and most important**: what am I doing wrong and why? How can I fix my code to make animation work?
- **Second question**: `spriteWithSpriteFrameName` is **deprecated**. Which method should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

I think you forget to set the delay for CCAnimation. I am not familiar with 2.0, but I guess there should be a method to set the Delay. or you may create an array of SpriteFrames first, then use the method

```
CCAnimation::create(array,delay);
```

Second:

```
CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName();
```